# how to create a table when value is passed in procedure in oracle?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g

I made a procedure which takes value and makes table which is:

```
create or replace procedure offc.temp(data1 varchar2(200)) is
   var1 varchar2(4000);
BEGIN
   var1:='create table offc.temp'||data1||'(
          id number)';
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE var1;
end;
```

I got error when I made the procedure :

```
[Warning] ORA-24344: success with compilation error
1/35    PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "(" when expecting one of the following:
          := . ) , @ % default character
          The symbol ":=" was substituted for "(" to continue.
 (11: 0): Warning: compiled but with compilation errors
```

Why is this error coming as I want to create table by passing value to procedure.

Comment: just replace `varchar2(200)` with `varchar2`

Answer (score 0):

You can't put the length in the parameter types

```
create or replace procedure offc.temp(data1 varchar2) is
   var1 varchar2(4000);
BEGIN
   var1:='create table offc.temp'||data1||'(
          id number)';
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE var1;
end;
```

Comment: Code only answers are generally considered low quality. Could you add an explanation to your answer.